# Problems reinstalling/uninstalling AVG .Anti-Virus Free Edition

Tags: anti-virus, avg-antivirus

I tried to upgrade my AVG Anti-Virus Free Edition installation, but halfway the installation I had to stop Windows (my computer was not responding) and now the AVG User Interface says "There are no active components".

So I tried a new installation but the program keeps on giving errors. I also tried to uninstall the current installation (uninstall and also repair) but I keep getting error messages:

[image: AVG error]

Can anybody help me? How can I remove the current installation?

I'm using Windows Vista Business edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check Task Manager and kill any AVG components
- Check Add/Remove Programs/Programs and features and see if there is anything in there
- Re-run the setup and see if it creates a tempoary folder with a setup.exe/unistaller.exe and run them.
- Have a look at [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html)

Comment: I did (first 2 steps). There are no AVG processes running. Only under Services a service called AVG WatchDog. But I can't stop this service, when I choose Stop it says "Access is denied", where I am the administrator

Comment: try in Safe Mode? (Tap F8 when Vista starts up)

Comment: I finally succeeded to reinstall AVG: first a run of Revo Uninstaller (thanks @tombull89), it starts the uninstall program, same error, but I continued Revo, it removed the registry entries and all the AVG files, after that I did a new AVG installation and now it works fine

Comment: FYI, just found this: AVG Remover at http://www.avg.com/nl-en/download-tools